# Как в scrapy с помощью поиска по css убрать теги

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-scraping

```
In [137]: f_part.css("table tbody").get()                                                                                                    
Out[137]: '<tbody>\n    <tr>\n      <td><code class="s-r">some</code></td>\n      <td>abrakadabra</td>\n      <td>lol</td>\n      <td>haha <a href="hm.html#zx-wd-gf">zzzzz</a> oabcdefgh</td>\n    </tr>\n  </tbody>'
```

Я хочу оставить только текст. Убрать хтмл теги.
Конечно, я могу убрать теги с помощью `from w3lib.html import remove_tags` но хочется сделать именно с помощью скрапи css.

```
In [138]: f_part.css("table tbody ::text").get()                                                                                             
Out[138]: '\n    '
```

и

```
In [139]: f_part.css("table tbody::text").get()                                                                                              
Out[139]: '\n    '
```

В общем попытки увенчались не удачей.
Как правильно получать текст с тега, используя `css` в скрапи?

Comment: не оно ? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041420/using-css-with-scrapy-to-extract-all-text-without-tags-failing

Comment: Scrapy не рекомендует использовать элементы <tbody> в выражениях XPath

Comment: вот на английском `Since Developer Tools operate on a live browser DOM, what you’ll actually see when inspecting the page source is not the original HTML, but a modified one after applying some browser clean up and executing Javascript code. Firefox, in particular, is known for adding <tbody> elements to tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use <tbody> in your XPath expressions.`